# Are 'ages' and 'aged' acceptable in those sentences?

Tags: word-choice

> I teach children aged 10 to 14.
>
> I teach children ages 10 to 14.

Comment: Wonder if there should have been an ***of*** in the second sentence? Or a comma, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is grammatical. The second one is not. You can change it with *I teach children whose ages vary from 10 to 14.*

EDIT upon comment: It seems I was mistaken in my initial answer and the second example is also grammatical. FumbleFingers' comment has the appropriate link to prove this.

Comment: I have found those two in a book published by MIT. It might be a typo then.

Comment: *The second is not grammatical?* Tell that to [821,000 published writers](http://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&q=%22not+sure+when+it+happens%22&btnG=#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22children+ages%22&pbx=1&oq=%22children+ages%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1464871l1469178l1l1469765l15l15l0l0l0l0l268l2209l3.10.2l15l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=5cc1ae9b34eaacd8&biw=1262&bih=764) indexed in Google Books!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In all honesty, I had never seen this before. I'd encountered "ages 10-15" (as an example), without the noun modifier preceding it. I'll edit my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: And the "ages 10-15" I'd seen was always isolated, i.e. in book covers or children's games, not part of a sentence, as in "Suitable for ages 10-15".

Comment: Since "ages 10 to 14" modifies "children", I'd like to see a comma there.