# The grammaticality and function of "people ages 20 to 30" (as opposed to "people aged 20 to 30")

Tags: grammaticality, participial-phrases, grammatical-roles

I have seen/heard constructions similar to "people ages 20 to 30" many times. However, several discussions, including questions on ELU, suggest the aforementioned construction is ungrammatical/typo: see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314748/people-aged-from-15-to-24-vs-people-ages-from-15-to-24-which-is-grammatical), [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54833/are-ages-and-aged-acceptable-in-those-sentences), [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128262/what-do-children-aged-ages-5-to-11-years-old-know-about-the-sun-redundant), and [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/people-ages-aged-18-or-older.2941544/) (of course there was some debate over this issue). These questions all seem inconclusive and undetermined. It's intriguing how on the one hand there's a plethora of attestations of this usage all over the Internet and on the other you have people one after another saying it is ungrammatical and/or a typo, not without comments to the contrary.

Examples include:

> There, every day, dozens of **children ages 3 to 5** come to have adventures on Irvine’s more than 200 acres of woodlands, wetlands, and meadows. ([The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/education/archive/2018/04/early-childhood-outdoor-education/558959/))
>
> Teen suicide is a growing health concern. It is the third-leading cause of death for young **people ages 15 to 24**, surpassed only by homicide and accidents, according to the U.S. Center for Disease Control and Prevention. ([APA](http://www.apa.org/research/action/suicide.aspx))
>
> In 2012, 87.6 percent of **people ages 18 or older** reported that they drank alcohol at some point in their lifetime. ([NIAAA](https://www.niaaa.nih.gov/alcohol-health/overview-alcohol-consumption/alcohol-facts-and-statistics))

So can we definitely determine this construction is ungrammatical? If that's not the case, then how do we parse these sentences? I am having the same issue a lot of people apparently had/have. While **aged 15 to 24** is a participial phrase, what kind of phrase is **ages 15 to 24** and how does it modify the preceding noun? A [parse tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) would be very helpful.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77717/discussion-on-question-by-eddie-kal-the-grammaticality-and-function-of-people-a).

Comment: If you want a parse tree, what theory do you want it in?

Comment: @AzorAhai Either one. My Linguistics 101 was constituency-based, but I don't think I am too stupid to understand dependency analysis.

Comment: A parse tree is just a different representation of whatever grammar someone decides is involved. Rather like using a different font.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[1]  a.  *It is the third-leading cause of death for **young people ages 15 to 24**.*
       b.  *While parents are off shopping, **children ages 3 to 8** can play in the*
            *glass-enclosed child-care center.* 
       c.  *Nearly one-third of **the people ages 15 to 34**, and more than half of*
            ***those ages 35 to 44** had hypertension.*

1. **Acceptability.** It is true that some native speakers do not find constructions such as those in [1] acceptable (this is evident from the discussions on this website). (EDIT: as documented in Araucaria's answer on this page, this seems to be an AmE vs BrE split, with the construction being very standard in American English, but far less universally acceptable in British English.) Nevertheless, on the whole, balance of evidence shows that this type of construction is nowadays part of Standard English **at least in the context of news and in scientific/medical literature.** (And at least in American English.) Below, I will present several representative pieces of evidence for this, one of which is an **explicit endorsement** of this construction from a **style manual** ([*Urban Institue Editorial Style Guide*](https://web.archive.org/web/20220729145815/https://urbaninstitute.github.io/editorial-styleguide/index.html)).

2. **Syntactical analysis.** It is uncontroversial that **if** the sentences in [1] are acceptable, **then** the boldfaced parts are noun phrases (NPs). It is also uncontroversial that (**if** the sentences in [1] are acceptable, then) the constructions *ages 15 to 24* etc. are themselves NPs, functioning as some sort of dependent in the larger, **matrix** NP.

I have been unable to find a treatment of this particular construction in the literature. But, for what it's worth, it seems to me that there are at least two ways to analyze the function of these 'internal' NPs within their matrix NPs:

**(a) NP as a post-head modifier in a matrix NP.** True, NPs are rare in this function, but not unheard of. Examples include expressions such as ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468), p. 446)

[2] *a man **my age***                *shoes **this size***
      *the results **last year***      *houses **this side of the lake***

As CGEL says about these examples, 'modifiers with NP form are limited to those denoting **age**, size, and similar properties' (emphasis mine).

**(b) NP as a complement of the preposition *of*, where we have an ellipsis of the preposition.** On this account, *people ages 15 to 24* is really *people **of** ages 15 to 24*, where the preposition *of* has been ellipted. In the non-ellipted version, *ages 15 to 24* is a complement of *of*, and the whole preposition phrase (PP) *of ages 15 to 24* is a post-head modifier of *people*, which is the head of the matrix NP. In its discussion of post-head modifiers, CGEL says that (p. 445, emphasis mine)

> NPs, however, are rare because with modifiers, as with complements, dependent NPs are usually related to the head by means of a preposition, rather than directly. **Modifiers with the form of PPs are extremely common in post-head position**.

Of course, one could similarly say that the examples in [2] are all cases of preposition ellipsis (*a man **of** my age, shoes **of** this size, the results **from** last year, houses **on** this side of the lake*). Note, however, that CGEL does **not** do this. They don't explain why. All I can tell you is what I think, and it is this: to a linguist, an ellipsis is always a **last resort**, something one postulates to explain how a construction that doesn't seem to fit into the larger system of syntax could nevertheless fit into that system. But there is no reason why English should absolutely disallow NPs as post-head modifiers in a matrix NP; certainly there are other languages that allow them (and without any invocation of an ellipsis). Thus, we might as well say that such constructions are allowed, if rare. Other than this principle ('ellipsis is a last resort'), I do not know how to decide whether (a) or (b) should be preferred.

**Evidence of acceptability**

[Garner's Modern American Usage](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195161912) uses the following example in its discussion of *enclose/inclose* on p. 297 (emphasis mine):

> *While parents are off shopping, **children ages 3 to 8** can play in the glassed-inclosed [read glass-enclosed or glassed, enclosed] child-care center.*

The *Merriam-Webster Dictionary* gives the following sentence as an example of usage in its entry for *age* [(here)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/age). The sentence is taken from an article in a major daily newspaper:

> *Nearly one-third of **the people ages 15 to 34**, and more than half of **those ages 35 to 44** had hypertension.*
>    —*Milwaukee Journal Sentinel*, "Too young for a stroke? Think again.," 9 May 2018 [(source)](https://web.archive.org/web/20211019100039/https://www.jsonline.com/story/sponsor-story/froedtert/2018/05/09/too-young-stroke-think-again/34562895/)

The [*Urban Institue*](https://www.urban.org/) *Editorial Style Guide* [(here)](https://web.archive.org/web/20220729145815/https://urbaninstitute.github.io/editorial-styleguide/index.html) gives the following recommendations for 'age':

> **AGE**
>
> ***children ages 2 to/through 6**, 9 to/through 15 (not aged 2 to/through 6), between the ages of 9 and 15*

This construction is not restricted to plurals:

In *Clinical Handbook of Psychotropic Drugs for Children and Adolescents: 3rd ed* we find

> *Approved in the USA for **children age 7 and above*** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=sawVBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA46&dq=%22children%20age%22&pg=PA46#v=onepage&q=%22children%20age%22&f=false)

And in *Straight A's in Pediatric Nursing*, we have numerous instances of constructions such as

> ***A child age 4** should be able to stand on one foot for about 5 seconds.*
> *For **a child age 6**, have him stand on one foot with his arms folded across his chest for 5 seconds.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Amhpa3N7ekQC&pg=PA53&dq=%22a+child+age%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo0bf9pZDbAhVI22MKHRA-DboQ6AEIIjAD#v=onepage&q=%22a%20child%20age%22&f=false)

All of the above is just the tip of the iceberg. This type of construction is simply **super-well attested** in **edited scholarly and journalistic publications**, written by **well-educated native speakers**.

Let me close with just one final example: the journal article 'The Processing and Interpretation of Verb Phrase Ellipsis Constructions by Children at Normal and Slowed Speech Rates' by Sarah M. Callahan, Matthew Walenski, and Tracy Love (J. Speech Lang. Hear. Res. **55,** 710-725, 2012; full text available [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3703828/)):

> ***Forty-two children ages 5 through 12 years** listened to VP ellipsis constructions...*
> *In this study, we investigated how **children ages 5 through 12** processed and interpreted sentences with VP ellipsis constructions and an embedded reflexive anaphor.*
> *Our results suggest that **children ages 5 through 12** have achieved adultlike performance for the...*

Comment: I'm not sure what the hoo-hah about the other answer is (which directed me here), but this is one of the best answers I've ever seen here. I'm going to nick it and study it properly when I have sufficient time. The other answer is under-researched and naive.

Comment: One reason to prefer just the NP analysis, is that we have NP modifiers for which there is no paraphrase with a preposition. So, for example, we have phrases like *every week*, or *last year* or *this time*. Another problem with the preposition elipsis theory is that once we allow for elipted items we could equally say they're all reduced relative clauses instead - or many other types of phrasal category. There don't seem to be any tests we can do to verify the theory. Invisible items supported by untestable theories isn't a  very attractive proposal. That's just my tuppenceworth. Nice post +1

Comment: All the baseless salvos notwithstanding, I feel deeply honored that my question has elicited such an answer. There's a couple things in it I am not sure I fully understand, but I guess I need more time on it. I don't understand how this answer could have received so little attention. Seeing this answer, the repeated attempts to put down my question by a few really feel trifling compared to getting my question answered to such a pleasant extent. Thanks to all who helped in clarifying/answering my question.

Comment: @Araucaria I've seen phrases such as 'every week', 'last week', 'this way' classed separately as 'adverbial objectives'; CGEL classes say 'home' as an [intransitive] preposition when not obviously used otherwise. I don't like either the NP or the IntP analysis.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The adverbial objective analysis is the same as the CamGEL one really, the oly difference is the terminology. Here adverbial=modifier and objevtive=noun phrase. So the 'adverbial objective' analysis seems good to me, because it retains the clear division between the phrasal category (objective) and the grammatical relations (adverbial). I prefer modifier to adverbial, because it does not have the word *adverb* in it, but that's just a terminological difference, not a difference of analysis.

Comment: @Araucaria There is a larger issue: whether these things should be lumped with prototypical prepositions. As you say, 'last week' / 'yesterday' don't have a convenient undeleted form. 'Home' is a relict form here, meaning 'at home' or 'to home'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Unrelated to your specific comments, I might have some interesting info re the OQ in my post below.

Comment: This answer deserves an upvote just for the self-referentiality of the last paragraph.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. After more than four years, I realized I have a question about your comment. If I understand you correctly, you say that in *every week*, (i) *week* is an NP, and (ii) it is a modifier. The latter presumably means that (iii) *every* is the head of *every week*.  All three of these seem incorrect to me: (i) since *week* is a countable singular noun, it normally requires a determinative. But if *week* is a modifier, then *every* must be the head, in which case it can't be the determinative of *week*.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Better to say, it seems, that *week* is the head, a 'nominal', and that *every* is its determinative. But then *every week* is not an example of an NP modifier. Similar comments apply to your other suggested examples.

Comment: @linguisticturn Actually, that's not what I meant by NP modifier! What I meant is that NPs like *every day* also function as modifiers (of both other NPs but also in VPs and clauses) in a similar way to NPs such as *ages xyx* or *my age.* There's no reconstruction available with a preposition there: *parties every week were part of the problem* versus **parties on/of every week*. So once you accept such NPs as NPs and not PP's with a missing P, there's not much motivation for a missing P analysis in the other cases. Sorry, should have been clearer.

Comment: @linguisticturn So, obviously, yes, *every* is a determinative in *every week*! (I was using 'NP modifier' to mean 'an NP functioning as a modifier', not 'a modifier of an NP.'

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Oh, I see. Yes, agreed… Although I guess one can always postulate ever more radical kinds of ellipsis, not necessarily just of prepositions (a possibility you also mentioned in your comment), e.g., *parties [that take place]/[taking place] every week were part of the problem*.

Answer (score 6):

To supplement Linguisticturn's excellent answer, there is a little bit to be said about a  very marked US/UK split on the idiomaticity and grammaticality of posthead NP modifiers using the noun *age*.

COCA, the Corpus of Contemporary American English, gives a roughly 54%/46% split between [*people aged*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=66298024) and [*people ages*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=66273189), with 152 and 131 tokens each (adjusting for false positives). This shows that both of these are idiomatic and grammatical in American English. It also shows that the two constructions exist in competition with each other.

However, the British National Corpus has 154 tokens for [*people aged*](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/?c=bnc&q=66298013) and zero tokens for [*people ages*](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/?c=bnc&q=66297935). This, contrastingly, indicates that noun phrases using *age* are ɴᴏᴛ used as posthead NP modifiers in British English.  The issue here is one of the nature of the modifier, of course, not of the noun being modified. A search on  COCA for [*men ages*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=66298125) gives 79 tokens. On BNC, [there are none at all](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/?c=bnc&q=66298131).

So there seems to be a clear dialect split between British and American English. British English speakers don't freely use *ages* noun phrases to modify other nouns—indeed, they  may find this ungrammatical. In American English, however, this is quite acceptable, and is almost as common as using an *aged* adjective phrase.

Comment: Interesting! As a native BrE speaker, I have no problem with this use of "ages".

Comment: @AndyT Yes, me too! (although, I'd probably use the adjective *aged* version when writing myself)

Comment: Yes, a good addition. I'm also in line with your comment here.

Comment: Very interesting...! I've edited my answer to incorporate some of this information (in the paragraph following [1]).

Comment: Here's a recent example showing perhaps greater acceptance in the UK: << Virtual recycling games and activities - for children ages 7+  >>[...recycleforgreatermanchester.com › event › virtual-recy...](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22children+ages%22&rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ei=UhetX4KYMvmr1fAP89GW6AM&start=20&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiCiY7J7vzsAhX5VRUIHfOoBT04ChDy0wN6BAgHEDc&biw=1320&bih=744) (I couldn't find the quote easily within the file, hence the Google search link).